# How to install Fedora raw.xz ARM images onto a system?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I download several systems [here](https://arm.fedoraproject.org/). The file format is not ISO, but raw.xz.

How to install a raw-file system?

Answer (score 1):

Use the intended [Fedora ARM installer](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/F26/Installation#Fedora_Arm_Installer).

The image itself is a complete partition image:

```
user@host: unxz Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-27-1.6-sda.raw.xz
user@host: file Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-27-1.6-sda.raw
Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-27-1.6-sda.raw: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x4,4,1), end-CHS (0x78,119,2), startsector 2048, 59392 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x83, active, start-CHS (0x78,120,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,2), startsector 61440, 999424 sectors; partition 3 : ID=0x82, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,2), startsector 1060864, 499712 sectors; partition 4 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,2), startsector 1560576, 2453504 sectors
```

Comment: After the xz extraction, I should run `fedora-arm-image-installer --image=Fedora.raw --target=Bananapi --media=/dev/mmcblk0`? I should  write it into a usb or a disc?

Comment: That depends on the device where you want to use Fedora on. If you're using a Raspberry Pi 2 or 3, you'll most likely want to install it on a SD card. Please refer to the [installation instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi?rd=Raspberry_Pi) on the Fedora website.

Comment: The ‘Fedora ARM installer' webpage is chaos. Can you list the basic steps of using it? What is its difference with ISO-file installation? I need to install it on my Dell server.

Comment: I disagree that the webpage is "chaos". Within minutes I can find any question that you have posted so far. Without further information on the dell server, I can't even tell if it is supported. Check on the [Supported Hardware and Devices](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM#Supported_Hardware_and_Devices) site whether it is listed. As for this question, I already gave a legitimate answer. If you have other questions, please ask a new one (and mark this one as answered).

Comment: Wait, hold on. Do you have an _ARM_ Dell server?